# How to get last 3 elements from a list without knowing the length of list

Tags: python

I need to get last three elements of the list without evaluating the length of the list. Following code displays what I expect:

```py
sports = ['cricket', 'football', 'volleyball', 'baseball', 'softball', 'track and field', 'curling', 'ping pong', 'hockey']
last = ['curling', 'ping pong', 'hockey']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

```py
last = sports[-3:]
```

this should do it

Comment: @Thesenix Could you please mark this answer as accepted?